# A Question Concerning My Question and My Answers

Tags: discussion

I asked on question about anyone knowing a good harmonizer that would work accurately up into the third octave of the flute. It is a question I've been searching for an answer to for months, after trying several units that failed. I was informed that my question was inappropriate by somebody on the music forum, so I consequently deleted it. YET, I see all sorts of similar questions about gear and equipment on the boards that aren't objected to, and, in fact, are readily responded to. What gives? Is it something about being new here?

Next: My answers seem to now draw a what I consider undue criticism.

I was rather excited to join in, but I'm now feeling like this is a closed shop?

Moderators and leadership HONEST response would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some links to examples to make it simpler for us to know which ones you are referring to

Answer (score 3):

The only question I can see of yours is a shopping/recommendation question, so it is explicitly off topic here, as stated in the site scope. If you read the site scope again you will get a better idea.

> Anyone know of a good harmonizer that works well with flute throughout its range? We've tried a bunch of different harmonizers, and none of them can handle the third and fourth octaves on the flute. In fact, most of them go into digital meltdown even in the second octave. We're reduced to using an octaver for voicing (using the POG2 with great results), but Forrest (my arranger/composer husband) would really like to utilize other interval combinations, including stacking them.
>   We've tried a bunch of different ones, units up to like $1500 USD, but, despite the reps claiming they'll work, they don't. After getting the units shipped in to actually try them in studio, they fail at their job. Calls to the manufacturer then reveal that, no, they don't work in the soprano or high soprano ranges. Of course, they don't mention that in the specs! Another flutist/guitarist owned a VoiceLive3 and kindly tried it with his flute. It successfully went up to third octave G#, failing at third octave A. Unfortunately, it's no longer available and the manufacturer doesn't seem to offer anything similar to it. PLEASE NOTE: They have to allow at least a solid amount of patches to be custom-programmed.

If you see other questions that look like shopping recommendations, please flag them so moderators can review them.

And I can see only one answer of yours with a comment that isn't complimentary.

So I'm unsure as to what you are talking about here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65106/discussion-between-dr-mayhem-and-dlkeur).

Comment: Hello, long time no talk. When you say "Site Scope" here, do you mean https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic?

Comment: Hi topo - good to see you back. Yes, that page has in the Do Not Ask section: shopping help — including product or music search — or buying/selling advice or recommendations

Comment: Been busy, will doubtless be around more sometime in the future! Though I don't disagree with anything you've said here or in the chat, I do admit that's one of the 'wordings' that could be a little clearer... sometimes I've wondered why the wording doesn't say something more like "questions that ask for specific product recommendations", as it seems that it's *that* in particular that the community doesn't want, while more general advice and recommendations are often fine. Just thought i'd mention it again as it seems that this user also misunderstood the intent of that wording.